# Discord.js V13 -- Store persisting hidden data on the message object

Tags: discord.js

I have coded a bot to send a message response to a given command, `!a`. I want to store additional data on the message object, so that if the user reacts to that message the bot can read the hidden data property and know the original message resulted from `!a`.

Ideas I had:

- Create a custom property on the message object: Message.Custom_Prop
- Hijack an unused property: Maybe Message.webhookId?
- Store hidden text in the form of an embed or message content.

I haven't been able to get any of these to work though.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I can think of is to store an array of message IDs that were triggered by `!a`. Something like this:

```
// At the start of your script
const commandResponses = [];

// Logic for sending the command response
message.channel.send("response here").then(msg => commandResponses.push(msg.id));

// Checking whether the message was a response
if (commandResponses.includes(reaction.message.id)) {
  // It's a response so do stuff here
}
```

(Not tested so it's possible that this won't work)

Comment: I really wanted to store the data ON the object itself for permanence.

Comment: @JeremiahDuane you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be easily hijacked. For example, you can use `nonce` field for this task.

```
client.channels.cache.get(<...>).send({
    content: 'hello there',
    nonce: 'hijacked!!!'
})
```